# OOP can't use define in variable

Tags: php, oop, class, variables

Why can't you use `defines` when creating a variable in a class? What can I do to get past this? (the define is a table prefix (db))

Like this:

```
class foo {
    public $bar = FOO."bar";
}
```

That gives me the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   '.', expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: It's called a [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php), `define()` is the function that makes constants.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only declare properties with constant expressions. Here, the concatenation operator is illegal (hence the parse error), not the `FOO` constant.

```
public $bar = FOO."bar";
```

One way past this is to initialize it in the constructor instead. You can still use the constant, along with concatenating it with your string.

```
class foo {
    public $bar;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->bar = FOO."bar";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the constructor to initialize the value:

```
<?php
define("FOO", "test");

class foo {
    public $bar;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->bar = FOO . "bar";
    }
}

var_dump(new foo());
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not that you cannot use `defines`. You cannot use operators when initializing variables.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you cannot define class variables using operators, if the value needs to be dynamic, then the assignment must occur in a function.

When using constants, it can be useful to use class constants instead of defining your constants in the global scope. They're defined using the keyword `const`, and accessed using the `self::` operator.

```
class foo 
{
    const BAR = 'test';

    public $baz;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->baz = self::BAR . 'bat';
    }

}
```

Class constants can also be accessed outside an instance statically: `foo::BAR`, so you can use constants from classes in other contexts, but are not automatically in the global scope as a constant defined with `define`.

```
$some_var = foo::BAR;
echo $some_var;
// output: test
```